# Symantec Scan Engine and Symantec Endpoint Protection

Tags: c#, .net, antivirus, virus-scanning, symantec

We have a website where users upload different files of type tif, zip, csv and pdf.

What we want is to check every file provided by users for viruses before uploading the file to its final location where it is consumed by other services.

We have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed on our server which checks for viruses, malware etc.

However, Symantec Endpoint Protection does not provide .NET SDK for scanning files from applications. Therefore, I want to use Symantec Scan Engine as it provides .NET SDK which can be easily integrated in .NET applications.

I have the following concerns:

1. Does the SDK (of Scan Engine) allow a .NET application to scan files without sending the file to any other server? Or does it send the file to one of Symantec's servers for content checking?
2. How can I download the SDK to test locally? Is it possible to try it before fully buying it?
3. Has anybody talked to the support team of Symantec Endpoint protection? How can I communicate to them?

Comment: Wouldn't one option be to use the SEP command line tool? https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article?legacyId=TECH104287

Comment: It's a good option. However, it is very slow. When I ran the command in cmd, it did not provide any result. I also checked AVMan.log and there was only information about start time and end time. 

Or do we have another specific SEP tool ?